# Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'setTitle'

Tags: swift

I have this error and can't find a way to solve it..

```
@IBAction func startBouton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if !isTimerWorking {
        // (...)
        startBouton.setTitle(title:"PAUSE", for: UIControlState.normal)
    } else {
        // (...)
        startBouton.setTitle(title:"START", for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

}
```

I searched on internet, and UIButton I found that UIButton **has** a setTitle member..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `sender` parameter (which is the `UIButton` rather than `startBouton` (which is a function). The type in the error message gives you all the information you need:

```
(UIButton) -> ()
```

is a function that takes a `UIButton` and returns `nil`. So you're obviously not calling `setTitle` on a `UIButton` instance.

Answer (score -1):

Do you remember when u made the connection on the viewController.swift file? you control dragged the button to the code and created a connection . when you did that it created a startbouton function. A popup window opened. You selected action then you named the button. startbouton. and selected UIButton. 
You created an action. 
you have to also create an outlet for the same button.
do that same thing .
Control drag the same button to the code.
Popup window will appear.
on that don't do action but OUTLET
then name the button. Startbouton1
now when you use startbouton1.setTitle() it won't give you the error. 
Ya this was annoying .

crate connection 2 times. Once for the action nd one for outlet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question was already answered, and your answer does not appear to add anything useful. Please read this: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)